# Kubernetes cluster unable to pull images from DigitalOcean Registry

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, digital-ocean, docker-registry

My DigitalOcean kubernetes cluster is unable to pull images from the DigitalOcean registry. I get the following error message:

```
Failed to pull image "registry.digitalocean.com/XXXX/php:1.1.39": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image 
"registry.digitalocean.com/XXXXXXX/php:1.1.39": failed to resolve reference 
"registry.digitalocean.com/XXXXXXX/php:1.1.39": failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized
```

I have added the kubernetes cluster using DigitalOcean Container Registry Integration, which shows there successfully both on the registry and the settings for the kubernetes cluster.

[image]

I can confirm the above address `registry.digitalocean.com/XXXX/php:1.1.39 matches the one in the registry. I wonder if I’m misunderstanding how the token / login integration works with the registry, but I’m under the impression that this was a “one click” thing and that the cluster would automatically get the connection to the registry after that.

I have tried by logging helm into a registry before pushing, but this did not work (and I wouldn't really expect it to, the cluster should be pulling the image).

It's not completely clear to me how the image pull secrets are supposed to be used.

My helm deployment chart is basically the default for API Platform:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "api-platform.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "api-platform.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  {{- if not .Values.autoscaling.enabled }}
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  {{- end }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      {{- include "api-platform.selectorLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
  template:
    metadata:
      {{- with .Values.podAnnotations }}
      annotations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      labels:
        {{- include "api-platform.selectorLabels" . | nindent 8 }}
    spec:
      {{- with .Values.imagePullSecrets }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      serviceAccountName: {{ include "api-platform.serviceAccountName" . }}
      securityContext:
        {{- toYaml .Values.podSecurityContext | nindent 8 }}
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-caddy
          securityContext:
            {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
          image: "{{ .Values.caddy.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.caddy.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.caddy.image.pullPolicy }}
          env:
            - name: SERVER_NAME
              value: :80
            - name: PWA_UPSTREAM
              value: {{ include "api-platform.fullname" . }}-pwa:3000
            - name: MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ include "api-platform.fullname" . }}
                  key: mercure-publisher-jwt-key
            - name: MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ include "api-platform.fullname" . }}
                  key: mercure-subscriber-jwt-key
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
            - name: admin
              containerPort: 2019
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/run/php
              name: php-socket
          #livenessProbe:
          #  httpGet:
          #    path: /
          #    port: admin
          #readinessProbe:
          #  httpGet:
          #    path: /
          #    port: admin
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-php
          securityContext:
            {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
          image: "{{ .Values.php.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.php.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.php.image.pullPolicy }}
          env:
            {{ include "api-platform.env" . | nindent 12 }}
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/run/php
              name: php-socket
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - docker-healthcheck
            initialDelaySeconds: 120
            periodSeconds: 3
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - docker-healthcheck
            initialDelaySeconds: 120
            periodSeconds: 3
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
      volumes:
      - name: php-socket
        emptyDir: {}
      {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with .Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
```

How do I authorize the kubernetes cluster to pull from the registry? Is this a helm thing or a kubernetes only thing?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably your image pull secret is not correctly encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that API Platform automatically has a default value for imagePullSecrets in the helm chart, which is

`imagePullSecrets: []`

in [values.yaml](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/blob/e7c3973a8bef114d9a618b0589a1ea34b21c5603/helm/api-platform/values.yaml#L60)

So this seems to override kubernetes from accessing imagePullSecrets in the way that I expected. The solution was to add the name of the imagePullSecrets directly to the helm deployment command, like this:

`--set "imagePullSecrets[0].name=registry-secret-name-goes-here"`

You can view the name of your secret using `kubectl get secrets` like this:

`kubectl get secrets`

And the output should look something like this:

```
NAME                                      TYPE                                  DATA   AGE                                              
default-token-lz2ck                       kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      38d                                              
registry-secret-name-goes-here            kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson        1      2d16h
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem that you have is that you do not have an [image pull secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/) for your cluster to use to pull from the registry.

You will need to add this to give your cluster a way to authorize its requests to the cluster.

### Using the DigitalOcean kubernetes Integration for Container Registry

Digital ocean provides a way to add image pull secrets to a kubernetes cluster in your account. You can link the registry to the cluster in the settings of the registry. Under "DigitalOcean Kuberentes Integration" select edit, then select the cluster you want to link the registry to.

[image: DigitalOceanKubernetesIntegration]

This action adds an image pull secret to all namespaces within the cluster and will be used by default (unless you specify otherwise).

Comment: Unfortunately I have already done that as mentioned in my question. "I have added the kubernetes cluster using DigitalOcean Container Registry Integration, which shows there successfully both on the registry and the settings for the kubernetes cluster."

Comment: I am using the default `helm` deployment template from API Platform, and I wonder if that is somehow overriding the default image pull secret setup. I've included that in the code above for reference.

Comment: You could try unlinking, then re-linking through the interface. Another possibility is that you  are providing a different image pull secret through helm. If you are writing your own serviceAccount, then you should set its image pull secret to the one digital ocean creates for you. For my cluster, the name of the generated secret is the name of the container registry.